# solr atomic updates in XML format

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

This is the body of atomic update in JSON format. I copied the code from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents)

```
{"id":"mydoc","price":{"set":99},"popularity":{"inc":20},"categories":{"add":["toys","games"]}, "promo_ids":{"remove":"a123x"}, "tags":{"remove":["free_to_try","on_sale"]}}
```

How do I write the same in XML format?

Answer (score 4):

See the [section for Optional Attributes](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22) at the wiki page for the XML update format.

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="employeeId">05991</field>
    <field name="office" update="set">Walla Walla</field>
    <field name="skills" update="add">Python</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```